# Replace asterisks in x-spam-level by different character

Tags: debian, amavis

Is it possible to have Amavis use something else than the `*` character for the `X-SPAM-LEVEL` header (preferably the `x` character) – and if so, how to accomplish that?

#### TL;DR

Background: while the power-user could filter with regex, for the end user "wildcard matches" are much easier to deal with. `X-SPAM-LEVEL matches 'xxxx*'` is much easier to read (and type) than `X-SPAM-LEVEL matches regex '\*{4,}'` – for the "normal end-user", I mean. I had that configured on my old server, where SpamAsassin was used via `spamd` (docs have `spam_level_char` for that, in my config it was `add_header all Level _STARS(x)_` – so I know it's possible there. My new server uses SA via Amavis, so it's a different thing here – and I couldn't yet figure how to tell Amavis.

I've already used up most of my Google-Fu, but couldn't find anything<sup>1</sup> (and yes, I've also explicitly used the search here on Serverfault, as well as on SU, without success).

---

<sup>**1:** except for a [post from 2003](https://sourceforge.net/p/amavis/mailman/message/15141241/) suggesting to patch the Amavis code directly, which is no option for me</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, Murphy. A minute after posting my question I've decided to try my luck prefixing the SA variable with `$sa_` – and Amavis obviously accepted my

```
$sa_spam_level_char = "x";
```

While waiting for incoming mails to show success (or not), I used this for a Google search – finding [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/amavis/mailman/message/17001762/) on the Amavis mailing list, stating:

> The character in a bar can be chosen by $sa_spam_level_char
>   and defaults to an asterisk.

Murphy again: when you need a spam message (to confirm), none comes in #D But with Amavis restarting without an error message, and the Amavis list stating this as well, it must be the answer – so I'll post it now (and accept it when confirmed).